# How do I keep parts (not all the same) of a string that match a regular expression in Teradata?

Tags: regex, substring, position, teradata

I want to keep parts of a string in my output. The problem is this parts can be many things.

My input data have a store name and a selling code that looks like garbage:

'Amazon Store cod14%359'

'Roses Market XYwK$p@#2'

'Amazon Store cod99#9ab'

'MyStore _89ab$$3'

There are many answers to do this using the store name in the output string, like

```
  regexp_replace(store, '(Amazon Store).*$', 'Amazon Store')
```

but this implies a rule for each of many stores (too much job, Regular Expressions are better than this!)

Theoretically, I should be able to do things like this:

```
       my $date = "2009-27-02";
       $date =~ s/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/$1-$3-$2/;
```

Here, year is carried to output string as $1, month as $3 and day is $2.

I would like to do something like this:

```
   sel store, 
       regexp_replace(store, '((Amazon Store)|(Roses Market)|(MyStore)).*$', '$1') as BetterStore
   from myDatabase
```

( I had tried a lot of syntax variations, with {}, [], \ and all I could wonder, without success...)

Does somebody know if this is possible, in Teradata?

Comment: Did you try `regexp_replace(store, '(Amazon Store|Roses Market|MyStore).*', '\\1')` or  `regexp_replace(store, '(Amazon Store|Roses Market|MyStore).*', '\1')`?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: And why regexp_replace to remove the "garbage" instead of regexp_substr to extract the "good"?

Comment: Did my suggestion at the top help?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, thanks! Sorry for the delay. `regexp_replace(store, '(Amazon Store|Roses Market|MyStore).*', '\1')`. I thought I had already tried this, but probably made some mistake. This solved the problem, thanks! @dnoeth, _regexp_substr_ is not useful in this case, because I have a lot of other store names that I want to keep unchanged if they do not fit the filter. _Replace_ is the tool to clean only the polluted strings. Thank you, people!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
regexp_replace(store, '(Amazon Store|Roses Market|MyStore).*', '\1')
```

*Details*:

- `(Amazon Store|Roses Market|MyStore)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one of three phrases
- `.*` - the rest of the line.